# Java/Webdriver - opening a Firefox instance - firefoxbinary and setenvironmentproperty

Tags: java, webdriver, xvfb

Im trying to launch a Firefox instance with webdriver, but I want to instruct it to use certain xvfb display.
I think something is wrong with my code, though

```
   FirefoxBinary ffox = new FirefoxBinary();
   ffox.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", "22");
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

As you can see, at no point there is any mention to the "new firefoxdriver()" to use that ffox setting, but when I put ffox in the brackets of FirefoxDriver, my code goes red, because it can't accept such thing.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set System property to use the FF binary. Refer here http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver